# Injecting Android Application in Roboguice 3 creates a duplicate

Tags: android, roboguice

When using Roboguice 3 I can see it behaves differently than version 2. When I have custom Application object:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    ...
}
```

then in another class:

```
@Inject
private MyApplication app;
```

This code injects another MyApplication object, not the one that was created during startup of the app. (Where in Roboguice2 this is not the case)

Binding:

```
public class InjectionModule extends AbstractModule
{
    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
        bind(MyApplication.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

does not change this behavior.

How can I add the global MyApplication object to the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a Provider for that. In you module bind your class to the provider: `bind(MyApplication.class).toProvider(ApplicationProvider.class);`

Your provider should look something like below: (haven't tested the code)

```
public class ApplicationProvider implements Provider<MyApplication> {
    @Inject 
    Context context;
    @Override
    public MyApplication get() {
         return (MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Haven't tested that, but I think it just moves the problem to the Context class. Should I bind MyApplication to Context?

Comment: No because the Context has a default binding in RoboGuice, your custom Application class has not. So the context will automagically work...